# Inversion of harmonic points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Show that if four harmonic $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ points are inverted with respect to a circle whose center is another point on the same line as the first ones, we obtain another four harmonic points.

I tried to make some simple math, but it does not come out. I know $(A, B;\; C, D) = −1,$ but how can I get to $(A^\prime, B^\prime;\; C^\prime, D^\prime) = −1$.

Comment: With homogeneous coordinates on the projective plane, you can start out by assuming $C=A+B$ and $D=A-B$.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually this works because if the points are harmonic then $C$ and $D$ are inverses wrt the circle with diameter $AB$, and inversion in another circle $\Gamma$ preserves the relationship.  I.e. $C'$ and $D'$ are inverses wrt the circle with diameter $A'B'.$

But let's approach this from basic principles.

- Let $PQ$ be the directed distance between $P$ and $Q$
- $(A, B; C, D)=\dfrac{AC\cdot DB}{CB\cdot AD}$
- let the circle $\Gamma$ have center $X$ and radius $r$
- if $P'$ is the inverse of $P$   then $PX\cdot P'X=r^2$
- then $AC = AX+XC = \dfrac{r^2}{A'X}+\dfrac{r^2}{XC'}
  =r^2\dfrac{A'X+XC'}{A'X\cdot XC'}=-r^2\dfrac{A'C'}{A'X\cdot C'X}$.
- Similarly for the other terms $DB,CB,AD.$
- plug this into $(A, B; C, D)$ and simplify/cancel to get $(A', B'; C', D')$